# Linear transformation with $N(T) \varsubsetneq R(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \to V$ be a linear transformation, then does exist a non-one-to-one linear transformation $T$ such that $N(T)\varsubsetneq R(T)$?

If $T$ is one-to-one then the conclusion is straightforward, but I'm more interested in a non-one-to-one $T$.

My work:

Suppose $T:V \to V$ be a linear transformation such that $N(T) \subset R(T)$.
Let $v \in N(T) $, therefore $T(v) = 0_v$
$\because N(T) \subset R(T) \implies v \in R(T) $, therefore $\exists w \in V$
s.t. $T(w) = v$ 
therefore $T(T(w)) = 0_v \,\forall \{w \in V\,|\,T(w) \in N(T) \} $

I'm stuck at this point and unable proceed further.

Comment: Please avoid titles that consist of nothing but mathjax, as they mess up some navigation shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example with proper inclusion, just extend Hanno's example: take $T\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $T(x,y,z) = (y,0,z)$. The range is $\mathrm{span}\Bigl( (1,0,0), (0,0,1)\Bigr)$, and the nullspace is $\mathrm{span}(1,0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

$T=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\:$ fulfills your request
since $N(T)= \left\langle\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle= R(T)\,$.

Pushing the nilpotency to the next dimension with
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\:$$
yields a proper inclusion:
$N(T)= \left\langle\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle\,$
versus $\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle =R(T)\,$

Comment: I'm looking for proper subset, here the two are equal